# JQ: Merge all entries in an array without hardcoding the key

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I have a json like this

```
[
    {
      "name": "hosts",
      "ipaddress": "1.2.3.4",
      "status": "UP",
      "randomkey": "randomvalue"
    },
    {
      "name": "hosts",
      "ipaddress": "5.6.7.8",
      "status": "DOWN",
      "newkey": "newvalue"
    },
    {
      "name": "hosts",
      "ipaddress": "9.10.11.12",
      "status": "RESTART",
      "anotherkey": "anothervalue"
    }  
]
```

I want to merge the objects and looking for some output like this

```
[
  
    {
      "name": "hosts", //doesn't matter if it is ["hosts"]
      "ipaddress": ["1.2.3.4", "5.6.7.8", "9.10.11.12"],
      "status": ["UP", "DOWN", "RESTART"],
      "randomkey": ["randomvalue"],
      "newkey": ["newvalue"],
      "anotherkey": ["anothervalue"]
    }
]
```

I can hardcode each and every key and do something like this - `{ ipaddress: (map(.ipaddress) | unique ) } + { status: (map(.status) | unique ) } + { randomkey: (map(.randomkey) | unique ) }`
The important ask here is the values are random and cannot be hardcoded.
**Is there a way i can merge all the keys without hardcoding the key here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reduce`, then `unique` would be one way:

```bash
jq '[
  reduce (.[] | to_entries[]) as {$key, $value} ({}; .[$key] += [$value])
  | map_values(unique)
]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": [
      "hosts"
    ],
    "ipaddress": [
      "1.2.3.4",
      "5.6.7.8",
      "9.10.11.12"
    ],
    "status": [
      "DOWN",
      "RESTART",
      "UP"
    ],
    "randomkey": [
      "randomvalue"
    ],
    "newkey": [
      "newvalue"
    ],
    "anotherkey": [
      "anothervalue"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dRxd_Nj2vGv)

Using `group_by` and `map`, then `unique` again would be another:

```bash
jq '[
  map(to_entries[]) | group_by(.key)
  | map({key: first.key, value: map(.value) | unique})
  | from_entries
]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "anotherkey": [
      "anothervalue"
    ],
    "ipaddress": [
      "1.2.3.4",
      "5.6.7.8",
      "9.10.11.12"
    ],
    "name": [
      "hosts"
    ],
    "newkey": [
      "newvalue"
    ],
    "randomkey": [
      "randomvalue"
    ],
    "status": [
      "DOWN",
      "RESTART",
      "UP"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WNCBFAgD3uC)